# Somehow like a two-dimensional intermediate value theorem for the double integral.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R}^2)$ with respect to the Lebesgue measure $m \times m$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$. Prove that if $$\iint_{\mathbb{R}^2}f(x,y)\,dx\,dy=0,$$then there exits a square $S_{a,b}=\{(x,y)\mid a \leq x \leq a+1, b \leq y \leq b+1\}$, such that $$\iint _{S_{a,b}}f(x,y)\,dx\,dy=0.$$

I tried to show that the integral $$\iint_{[a,a+x]\times [b,b+y]}f(s,t)\,ds\,dt$$ is absolutely continuous by Fubini's Theorem and Fundamental Theorem. And by the countable additivity of integration, I proved the integral on the whole plane is still A.C. However, I could not directly apply a theorem like the IVT for the single variable functions.

Is there any theorem for the two-dimensional case?

Comment: Try applying Fubini's theorem, is the first thing I would think of. I have not worked through the details but it seems as if it could work.

Comment: That's what I have done, but I cannot claim there is a square satisfying what we want.

Answer (score 2):

Let $g(a,b)=\iint_{S_{ab}} f(s,t) \, ds \, dt$. $g$ is a continuous real valued function on $\mathbb R^{2}$. If it is never zero it is always positive or always negative. [ Because its range is connected in $\mathbb R$].  If it is always positive then $\iint_{\mathbb R^{2}} f(s,t) \, ds \, dt >0$ because this integral is the sum of integrlas over $S_{nm}$ as $n,m$ vary over all integers.

Comment: But for the case some of the integrals are positive and some of them are negative, how can you explian it?

Comment: If some of them are positive and some are negative the function $g$ takes both positive and negative values. By IVP it takes the value $0$ for some $(a,b)$ and this is what you are trying to prove.